# Unable to open trivial text file with FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider

I'm going crazy, I used the new Android `FileProvider` in the past but I can't get it to work with a (trivial) just-created file in the Download folder.

In my `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` I call

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", output));
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

My FileProvider XML is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

In Genymotion emulator I always get, choosing Amaze Text Editor as target app:
[image]

While I can see the file content with HTML Viewer:
[image]

I can't understand this behavior and fix what should be a trivial thing like opening a pure-text file with the desidered text editor.

thanks a lot
nicola

Comment: Try with some other app. It looks like Amaze Text Editor has a bug, where it is trying to use `sh`(???) to read this in. At most, that works for a `Uri` with a `file` scheme.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare I tried some other apps but they don't show anything (blank page) or similar issue. IMHO pretty ridiculous something so trivial is so difficult to achieve with the new FileProvider.

Comment: Well, if it is working with HTML Viewer, then the problem is not in your app, but in the client apps. This is not uncommon, as not all developers listen to me when [I explain how to make this work](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). You could put code in that uses `Uri.fromFile()` on pre-Android 7.0 devices, to help with compatibility a bit. Otherwise, I don't have much in the way of good advice for you.

Comment: BTW, and FWIW, looking at the Amaze source code, I would expect this to work on a plain v3.2.1 build of Amaze.

Comment: Just tried with 3.2.1 Amaze, it's crashing. Sent feedback to developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are two problems here. One is a bug in your code that triggers a bug in Amaze, and one is a bug in Amaze that you can work around.

`setType()` has a nasty side effect: it wipes out your `Uri` in the `Intent`. It is the equivalent of calling `setDataAndType(null, ...)` (where `...` is your MIME type). That's not good. So, instead of putting the `Uri` in the constructor and calling `setType()`, call `setDataAndType()` and provide the `Uri` there.
This gets you past the initial Amaze bug, where [they fail to handle a `null` `Uri` correctly](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager/issues/1014).

Then, though, they try to open the `Uri` in read-write mode. You are only granting read access, so this fails. Their second bug is that they think that they get a `FileNotFoundException` when they cannot open the file in read-write mode, and at that point they try read-only mode. In reality, at least on Android 8.1, [they get a `SecurityException`](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager/issues/1015). You can work around this by providing both read and write permissions.

So, unless you specifically want to block write access, this code works:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", output), "text/plain");
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Didn't know about the `setType` wiping out the `Uri` in the `Intent`. [OT I'm a client of yours, bought your Busy Coder for Android years ago, excellent piece of work!]

Comment: @NicolaBeghin: Glad that you have it going! Sorry it took me so long to catch onto the problem. And thanks for the kind words!